# How to suspend VM/Thread in Eclipse whenever debugger gets first hit ANYWHERE, without putting any breakpoint?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Many times I came into situation while debugging in Eclipse that I **Don't Know** where to put break point! For example, I just need to know when a client make a request to server which method it hits for this request. As I don't know where it will hit , I can't put a break point.
Can anybody suggest this if this conditional break point functionality available in Eclipse or any plugin? Or any other solution?

Comment: What's API being used? For example, Servlet containers allow to define `filters` which can be set up to intercept _any_ HTTP request, so you can set breakpoint in filter code.

Comment: You should be able to figure the entry point out from the source code alone. How would you phrase your condition if you don't know what to look for?

Comment: If even *you* don't know where to put your breakpoint, how should a *tool* figure out where to put it? You have to come up with an initial guess by yourself :)

Comment: I know it's odd question, but as we suspend VM in eclipse on uncaught exception or when specific exception happen. We Don't know where and which line but eclipse can know and suspend. Same way we can create a tool to suspend VM on first hit on any method which gets the hit from client! It's perfect usecase.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Yeah, I have a facade in application. It's simple core java based application, but the facade itself have over 200 methods.GUI will call one of these methods, but I don't know whcih and that's I want to know. WITHOUT putting breakpoint in every 200 methods.

Comment: Well I'm going to be blunt and say this is a really infrequent use case that, frankly, demands you set your 200 breakpoints, and in the future, add some tracing options.

Comment: @supernova Still, there must be some plumbing code between GUI and facade and you can put breakpoint in that plumbing code (even if it's JDK RMI, you should be able to put breakpoint inside JDK code with Intellij IDEA)

Comment: @nitind Use case is very obvious as I mentioned earlier. Actually The project I am working is legacy and quite big codebase. I need to work on a GUI method which update server / database. Now I don't know which method to change as I don't know where flow will hit server. Note : I know I can use profiler or stack trace but I am looking for some eclipse breakpoint solution.